# Handling size_t in a generic selection

Tags: c, c11, size-t

Is is possible to define a type-generic macro that supports all standard (unsigned) integer types, and also `size_t`?

`foo((size_t)42)` works with the example below as long as `size_t` refers to one of the standard unsigned integer types. But does the standard guarantee anywhere that this is the case, or could `size_t` also refer to an extended integer type?

```
void foo_bool(_Bool x);
void foo_uchar(unsigned char x);
void foo_ushort(unsigned short x);
void foo_uint(unsigned x);
void foo_ulong(unsigned long x);
void foo_ullong(unsigned long long x);

#define foo(x) _Generic((x), \
    _Bool: foo_bool, \
    unsigned char: foo_uchar, \
    unsigned short: foo_ushort, \
    unsigned: foo_uint, \
    unsigned long: foo_ulong, \
    unsigned long long: foo_ullong)(x)
```

Comment: One problem is that [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is just an *alias* of another type (usually `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`). It's not its own distinct type, and therefore can't be use with C generics together with the type it's an alias of.

Comment: I wonder if it would be useful to have a new version of `_Generic` that uses the *first* matching type. It seems to have been designed mainly to implement `<tgmath.h>`, which only needs to support the three standard floating-point types, but there are a lot of integer types that are `typedefs` and can't easily be used with `_Generic`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes - first match is a great idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is is possible to define a type-generic macro that supports all standard (unsigned) integer types, and also `size_t`?

Yes - with nesting.

`size_t` *commonly* matches a standard integer type like `unsigned, unsigned long, unsigned long long`, yet that is not *required* by C.  The trick becomes how to use `_Generic` when `size_t` is the same as a standard type and when it is not a standard type.  A similar issue  applies to `uintmax_t`.

```
void foo_size_t(size_t x) { (void)x; puts("size_t"); }
void foo_bool(_Bool x) { (void)x; puts("bool"); }
void foo_uchar(unsigned char x){ (void)x; puts("unsigned char"); }
void foo_ushort(unsigned short x){  (void)x; puts("unsigned short"); }
void foo_uint(unsigned x) { (void)x; puts("unsigned"); }
void foo_ulong(unsigned long x){ (void)x; puts("unsigned long"); }
void foo_ullong(unsigned long long x){ (void)x; puts("unsigned long long"); }
void foo_none(){ puts("TBD"); }

#define foo(x) _Generic((x), \
  _Bool: foo_bool, \
  unsigned char: foo_uchar, \
  unsigned short: foo_ushort, \
  unsigned: foo_uint, \
  unsigned long: foo_ulong, \
  unsigned long long: foo_ullong, \
  default: foo_none)(x)

// Catch `size_t` as `size_t`    
// If `size_t` is distinctive, apply the size_t function
// If `size_t` is not distinctive, others will be caught here too
#define bar(x) _Generic((x), \
  size_t: foo_size_t(x), \
  default: foo(x) \
  )

int main(void) {
  foo((float)1);  // What happens when type matching nothing
  foo(1lu);
  foo((size_t)1);
  bar((float)1);  // What happens when type matching nothing
  bar((size_t)1);
  bar(1lu);
}
```

Output

```
TBD
unsigned long
unsigned long  // Overlap when size_t matches a type, else TBD
TBD
size_t // expect this as unsigned long if size_t was distinctive.
size_t
```

Note that *creative* uses of `_Generic` may lead to issues as this expansion to C is still nascent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any implementation that uses a non-standard type for this.

If it is really only `size_t` you are worried about:

- You could have a `foo_size` function and put it in a `default`
  clause.
- You could use a compile test to error out if `size_t` is not among
  the standard unsigned types.

Something like

```
static_assert(
         _Generic(sizeof(int),
                  unsigned char: 1,
                  unsigned short: 1,
                  ...
                  unsigned long long, 1,
                  default: 0),
          "size_t not among the standard unsigned types");
```